# "access denied" in NET SHARE ... /DELETE?

Tags: windows, cmd

I get an unexpected "Access denied" error removing a share via `NET SHARE <share> /DELETE`, but only if executed immediately after unmapping the last mapping to the share, and only when run as a normal (not elevated) user.

I'd appreciate suggestions for a (non-Powershell) workaround, or some hint as to what is going on, or, at least some sympathy.  I'm trying to make this work in the context of a unit test that will run in somebody else's continuous integration environment, don't want to make too many assumptions about the Windows platform.

Run the script (below) with this command line:

```
> testbat
```

Observe it fails:

```
+> if NOT . == . sleep
+> net share uncpushd_test_cwd /delete
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.


+> net share uncpushd_test_cd1 /delete
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.
```

Run it with a magic delay (empirically determined to be 11 but not 10 seconds)

```
> testbatch 11
```

Observe it works:

```
+> if NOT .11 == . sleep 11   
+> net share uncpushd_test_cwd /delete
uncpushd_test_cwd was deleted successfully.


+> net share uncpushd_test_cd1 /delete
uncpushd_test_cd1 was deleted successfully.
```

One more test, run script with *no* delay but from an elevated command prompt.  Observe it works!  Every time!

Here's the whole script:

```
net share uncpushd_test_cwd=%TEMP%\pytest-of-bobhy\pytest-0\uncpushd
net use y: \\localhost\uncpushd_test_cwd /persistent:no
net share uncpushd_test_cd1=%TEMP%\pytest-of-bobhy\pytest-0\uncpushd\cdtest1
net use w: \\localhost\uncpushd_test_cd1
dir /s y:
dir /s w:
net use y: /delete
net use w: /delete
if NOT .%1==. sleep %1
net share uncpushd_test_cwd /delete
net share uncpushd_test_cd1 /delete
```

Comment: Caching.  The client is keeping the share open after the user closes it, to optimize the case where it is opened again straight away.  I'm not entirely sure why the client behaves differently in the elevated case, but I believe the two scenarios do look different to the networking layer.  (For example, only the restricted logon session gets saved network drive mappings restored during logon.)

Comment: A helpful suggestion!  But, sadly, I still see the error if I change: `net share <share>=<path>` to `net share <share>=<path> /cache:none`.

Comment: What did you change?

Comment: Added `/cache:none` to lines 1 & 3 of script above.

Comment: That's a different sort of caching, not relevant to your problem.  There *might* be a registry setting somewhere you can change to reduce the 10 second timeout before remote shares are closed.